# How to build a VC++ 2010 project on the command line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ide, msbuild

I need to build a VC++ 2010 project on Windows command line using MSBuild. The projects builds file using VC++ 2010 but it fails to build on the command line.

The failures are all in the form ***fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/.../*.hpp': No such file or directory**

I would like to know...

1) Why does this occur on the command line and not the IDE?

2) How can I add boost include and lib via the command line.

Comment: Have you double checked trivial faults like wrong paths (relative or absolute), not existing files, ..?

Comment: Are you allowed to use "devenv" directly?  Example: devenv /build "Release|win32" myproject.sln.  denenv can usually be found in your Program Files directory, where your VS2010 is installed, under "Common7\IDE".

Comment: @sharethis: It works in the IDE so I assume everything is set correctly. However, since it does not hurt to double check I'll do just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though it's deprecated, it's still supported if you want to build with the dev-studio directly via the cmd-line.  I've tried a few times to use MSBuild but keep going back due to issues.  e.g. `[path-to-tools]\devenv.exe my_project.sln /build "Release|x64" /project my_project`

Comment: This works really well for most of my solution except it can not compile the qt projects. It was never specified but Compiling Qt moc files is required.

Comment: should be able to make that part of a shell script in the process, or add it as a custom build step in VS if you desire...